# Is multiprocessing possible on a Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines, dc.parallel-comp

I recently created a parallel implementation of the Merge Sort, in which the sorting of several groups was accomplished by different processes, and was wondering if this was theoretically possible on Turing Machine?

Comment: Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in theoretical computer science. For more information about the scope, please see [help center](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Your question might be suitable for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) which has a broader scope.

Comment: Cross-posted on cs.se: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/42175/is-multiprocessing-possible-on-a-turing-machine.

Comment: What is "this"? Your question is not well defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a subtle question.

TMs are very much a sequential model of computation. So in some sense, TMs cannot (directly) model multiprocessing. However, TMs can do step-by-step simulations of the reductions a multiprocessor is carrying out. So TMs can do a sequential simulation of a parallel computation. Whether this a genuine model of parallel computation is debatable.

See also the discussion [Applicability of Church-Turing thesis to interactive models of computation](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/applicability-of-church-turing-thesis-to-interactive-models-of-computation).